# Error: Caught A Pass

Tags: word-meaning

In American football, it seems that some people would say:

> He caught a pass.

To my knowledge, a "*pass*" is an action.  So, the sentence would translate to:

> He caught an action.

Is my analysis wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A pass is an action, but it is also a physical thing. It is ball that is following a particular trajectory in space and time.

Can you not visualize a pass in your mind?

Comment: So, there is a dictionary definition that says "*a pass*" = "*the ball*"?

Comment: No, I said a ball following a particular trajectory. That is not just a ball. And no, that is not in the dictionaries I looked at, but then dictionaries are never completely exhaustive. Dictionaries follow usage, they don't determine usage.

Answer (score 0):

No it’s not wrong, anyone can catch actions. There are many people and many things that can catch actions such as video tapes, CDs, etc.

In arts, sculpture and picture are techniques of catching actions.

The verb [catch](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ADDWU4OFOaLMygPbiIHABQ#q=define+catch) is meant to intercept and hold actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as "He caught a ball which was passed [or thrown] to him".